# Redirect a Subdirectory url to another instance in AWS without changing URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have the following set up under one account:

- Domain: example.com with DNS administrated by AWS Route 53
- Hosting App: A Webapp with an AWS ELB under `www.example.com`
- Hosting Blog: A Wordpress Blog in a separate AWS EC2 Instance, at the moment with the link `blog.example.com`

What I want to achieve:
`Example.com/blog` -> Redirecting to the Blog in AWS EC2 Instance so that all the pages will be displayed like `example.com/blog/entry1` and `example.com/blog/entry2`, etc.,

My problem: Route 53 only allows subdomains like blog.example.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either setup path based routing in an Application Load Balancer (you would need to switch to an ALB if you are currently using a classic ELB), or place CloudFront in front of your domain and configure it with two sources.